# What is the expression for projective transformation?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, affine-transformations, image-transformations, projective-transformations

The following are the two types are projections that are generally used in image processing

1. Affine transformation
2. Projective transformation

Affine transformation is a backbone operation in neural networks also. It is expressed as

$$\mathbf{wx+b}$$
where $\mathbf{w, x, b}$ are matrices. In general, $\mathbf{x}$ is treated as an image in image processing.

Projective transformation is also a type of transformation on images and it may be different from affine transformation. I want to know whether it can be represented in terms of mathematical expression.

If yes, what is the expression for projective transformation?

Comment: What do you mean by "projective transformations"? Are you talking about [homographies](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21042/2444)? Maybe you could provide a little bit more context. Projective transformations definitely appear in the context of computer vision and computer graphics, but if you provide more context, it may be better. Anyway, maybe later I provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I explain in [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21048/2444) what a projective transformation (aka projectivity or homography) is. It's a function $h$ of the form $$h: \mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2,$$ where $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a **projective space**, so, essentially, a 3-dimensional Euclidean space of **homogenous vectors**.

You can also represent a homography as a $3 \times 3$ matrix $\mathbf{H}$, so that, when we apply this projective transformation to some input $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{P}^2$, we get $\mathbf{x}' \in \mathbb{P}^2$, so we can represent a projective transformation as follows.

$$\mathbf{H}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}'$$

So, basically, a projective transformation is a linear transformation between projective spaces.

You can generalize these ideas to higher-dimensional projective spaces, i.e. $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Although you can represent a projective transformation as a matrix multiplication, there's more to it. In fact, it's a linear transformation, with 8 degrees of freedom, between projective spaces. You can also view a homography as a generalization of other transformations, like **isometries**, **similarities**, and **affinities**. This is explained more in detail in chapter 2 of the book [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/algo-list/image-processing/vision/Richard_Hartley_Andrew_Zisserman-Multiple_View_Geometry_in_Computer_Vision-EN.pdf#page=42) (2nd edition) Richard Hartley and Andrew Zisserman.